# AWS File Upload to S3 with Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am trying to upload files into my `S3 bucket` using `AWS Lambda` in Java and i'm having some issues.

I am using `APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent` in my `AWS Lambda` function to get my file upload from `Postman`.

`request.getBody()` method of this event gives me a String representation of the image file whereas the `S3.putObject` takes as input an InputStream of the file to be uploaded.

How can I feed in `request.getBody()` to the `S3.putObject()` method in my Lambda code to make the File Upload work?

Comment: Sounds like the uploaded file is base64-encoded. Here's an example of code written in Java: https://github.com/CorkHounds/multipart-fileupload-java-lambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You may create a File and using FileWriter you may write the request.getBody() into it. 
2) You can go with PutObjectRequest object and put file created in Step1 into it.
3) s3Client.putObject(PutObjectRequest) will help you to put object to s3